# Why is the '1{0}' regex always matching with an empty string?

Tags: python, regex

```
import re

if re.match(r'1{0}', 'foo').group() == '':
   print(True)
```

Could someone explain why the condition is always satisfied?

The first character can be anything like:
`1{0}`, `2{0}`, `a{0}` etc

And why:

```
re.match(r'11{0}', 'foo').group()
# AttributeError: 'NoneType' object has no attribute 'group
```

Comment: Just saying match 1 zero times which is always true, its similar to having an empty regex

Answer (score 4, accepted):

From the [documentation](http://docs.python.org/2/library/re.html):

> ```
> {m}
> ```
>
> Specifies that exactly `m` copies of the previous RE should be matched; fewer matches cause the entire RE not to match. For example, `a{6}` will match exactly six `'a'` characters, but not five.

Therefore, `1{0}` would match exactly zero repetitions of the character `1`. This is the same as an empty regex, and would match anything.

Comment: Thx, but why:

`>>> re.match(r'11{0}', 'foo').group()

# AttributeError: 'NoneType' object has no attribute 'group`

Comment: Here, the `{0}` applies to the second `1` **only**.

Answer (score 3):

Because `{0}` tells it to match 0 repetitions of what it follows.  0 repetitions is an empty string.  An empty string always matches.